# Limits on one part of MySQL joins

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I'm using the following SQL query to find out what rooms a user is in, and what other users are in those rooms:

```
SELECT r1.room, r2.user 
FROM 
   rooms r1 JOIN rooms r2 ON r2.room = r1.room 
WHERE r1.user='foobar'
```

Sample rooms table:

```
room  |  user
a     |  user1
b     |  user1
c     |  user1
a     |  user2
a     |  user3
a     |  user4
```

I would like to limit the **other users in same rooms** part to 50 users returned per room, but not limit the amount of rooms. Is this possible in a single query?

**Example response for user1** (let's say I want to limit it to 3 users returned per room):

```
a, user1
a, user2
a, user3
b, user1
c, user1
```

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result? your question seems cinfusing.

Comment: I have added an example, thank you

Comment: So you want all rooms and a maximum of 50 users per room?

Comment: Yes, I only want to limit the users per room.. traditional limits limits the whole thing

Comment: why are there user1 in all records on the result?

Comment: that's actually not needed, I removed it

Comment: try my answer below `:D`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, with some interesting use of parameters, and nesting of derived tables:

```
SET @user = 'user1';
SELECT
  calclist.room,
  calclist.user
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      joinedlist.room 'room'
      , joinedlist.user 'user'
      , IF(joinedlist.room=@room, @rownum:=@rownum+1, @rownum:=1) 'count'
      , (@room:=joinedlist.room) dummy
    FROM
        (
          SELECT
            roommate_rooms.room,
            roommate_rooms.user
          FROM
            rooms user_rooms
            INNER JOIN rooms roommate_rooms
              ON user_rooms.room = roommate_rooms.room
          WHERE user_rooms.user = @user
          ORDER BY 
            roommate_rooms.room,
            roommate_rooms.user
          ) joinedlist
      JOIN (SELECT @rownum:=1) rn
  ) calclist
WHERE calclist.count <= 3
;
```

It can cope with the user being in any number of rooms, with or without any roommates; any number of other users who do not share any rooms; and it can cope with the data being entered 'out of order'. Worked example on [SQL Fiddler](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a338/3/0); and credit to [Jimmy's Blog](http://jimmod.com/blog/2008/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/) for how to use the dynamic parameters to do the counting.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    rooms a
WHERE   
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM    rooms b
            WHERE   a.room = b.room AND
                    a.user >= b.user
        ) <= 3
ORDER   BY a.Room, a.User
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/760a8/6)

Comment: This doesn't fit the requirements; the query should be finding out the rooms and room-mates of a single user, but this reports for all rooms and all users: see [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/565b2/1/0) for illustration where there are more rooms and more users.

Comment: @vincebowdren what made you think that you assumption is correct? having duplicate records on a table?

Comment: The duplicate record is a typo, but it's not important here. The thing I was trying to demonstrate was room e, which shouldn't be reported at all because user 1 isn't in this room.